# Excel VBA: Animation of moving object

Tags: vba, excel, object

This is a bit of an odd question. I have a speadsheet where I move some pictures around and I'm trying to create a more fluid "animation". The total movement is supposed to be 20, so I've tried to split it up in this example (I'm expecting to add a few frames if I get it to work). The problem however, is that you never see the first movement, only the last. Any ideas as to how something like this could be achieved?

I have tried adding ScreenUpdating and AplicationWait commands without luck.

```
Public PositionTop As Double
Public PositionLeft As Double
_______________________________________
Sub Animation()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    'Frame 1
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.Range(Array("RandomPicture")).Select
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Top = PositionTop + 10
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Left = PositionLeft
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Frame 2
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.Range(Array("RandomPicture")).Select
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Top = PositionTop + 20
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Left = PositionLeft
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    PositionTop = PositionTop + 20

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
______________________________________________
Sub ResetAnimation()
    PositionTop = 10
    PositionLeft = 20
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.Range(Array("RandomPicture")).Select
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Top = PositionTop
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Left = PositionLeft
    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `DoEvents`. Create a loop which increment the position and add `DoEvents` after the assignment of new position.

Comment: See if you can pick something from these codes I posted on Chandoo.org https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/basic-animation-examples-using-excel-vba-and-shapes.31038/

Answer (score 0):

Expounding above comment, you can try something like this:

```
Dim i as long
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 10 To 100 Step 10
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Left = i
        Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        DoEvents
    Next
End With
```

Above code will move your object every second by 10 steps. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will make the application wait an specific amount of time before running the rest of your code:

```
Public PositionTop As Double
Public PositionLeft As Double

Sub Animation()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    'Frame 1
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.Range(Array("RandomPicture")).Select
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Top = PositionTop + 10
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Left = PositionLeft
    End With
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") / 2) 'wait half a second
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'wait a second

    'Frame 2
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.Range(Array("RandomPicture")).Select
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Top = PositionTop + 20
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Left = PositionLeft
    End With
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") / 2)

    PositionTop = PositionTop + 20

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub

Sub ResetAnimation()
    PositionTop = 10
    PositionLeft = 20
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.Range(Array("RandomPicture")).Select
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Top = PositionTop
        .Shapes("RandomPicture").Left = PositionLeft
    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```